# How can I create a auto-incrementing array in a C++ while loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, while-loop

I have a while loop that uses stringstream/getline() to parse a string, however I'm having trouble manipulating the results from the loop. The loop splits the string up into 3 parts and puts each word in the variable "word" for that cycle of the loop. However, How can I then store each part in a variable or array so that I can use it outside the while loop?

The loop

```
string word;
    stringstream stream(cmdArgs.c_str());
    while( getline(stream, word, ' ') )
          // Manipulate results
```

The variable "cmdArgs" is the string.

Comment: Just to mention that [`boost::split()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3240174) can populate a `std::vector<std::string>` for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a vector lets you break the string into words and store each word individually, no matter how many:

```
string word;  
stringstream stream(cmdArgs.c_str());  
vector<string> words;  
while( getline(stream, word, ' ') )  
{  
    words.push_back(word);  
}
```

if you are confidant that there are exactly 3 words you could also just use a plain array:

```
string word;  
stringstream stream(cmdArgs.c_str());  
string words[3];  
int index = 0;  
while( getline(stream, word, ' ') )  
{  
    words[index++] = word;  
}
```

but you would overflow that array if the incoming string was longer than you expect.

Answer (score 4):

```
string word;
vector<string> words;
stringstream stream(cmdArgs.c_str());
while( getline(stream, word, ' ') )
{
    words.push_back(words);
}
// Manipulate results
```

See vector class: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

Comment: also see std::deque and std::list